# ViewModel not passing information correctly Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've fairly new to Asp.net core MVC and have spent days researching this and I can't find my error.

I'm simply trying to pass data from a ViewModel to a table in a view but the ViewModel isn't populating data.

Here's my code:

The model I'm currently working with (The others look the same with different columns):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Seating.Models
{
    public partial class Dth
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeEntered { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TimeCleared { get; set; }
        public bool? EmpSent { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int EmpPosition { get; set; }
        public int? RlfPosition { get; set; }

        public virtual Position EmpPositionNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual Position RlfPositionNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

VM:

```
using Seating.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Seating.ViewModels
{
    public class ListsVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<Dth> Dths { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Break> Breaks { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Lunch> Lunches { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Seating.Models;
using Seating.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Seating.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly db_a7e17a_seatingContext _context = new db_a7e17a_seatingContext();

        public HomeController(db_a7e17a_seatingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var tables = new ListsVM
            {
                Employees = _context.Employees.ToList(),
                Dths = _context.Dths.Where(n => n.TimeCleared == null).ToList(),
                Breaks = _context.Breaks.Where(n => n.TimeCleared == null).ToList(),
                Lunches = _context.Lunches.Where(n => n.TimeCleared == null).ToList(),
                Positions = _context.Positions.ToList()
            };
            return View(tables);
        }
```

And view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Seating.ViewModels.ListsVM>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header text-center">
        DTH
    </div>
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Dths)
            {
                <tr>
                    @item.EmployeeId
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm getting an error saying 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Dths'accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found.

I tried changing "IEnumerable" to "List" in the VM. I've read many solutions on stackoverflow. I've taken tutorials that have showed me how to set things up. As far as I can tell I'm following the tutorial code to the letter, even thought I'm clearly not somewhere.

I changed the model reference in the view to  @model IEnumerable<Seating.Models.Dth> instead of the VM. That works perfectly. So I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the VM since it works referencing the model directly without going through a VM.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change from `@model IEnumerable<Seating.ViewModels.ListsVM>` to `Seating.ViewModels.ListsVM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an object of type `ListsVM` that contains lists of different kinds of entities. And this object is passing to the view by `View(tables)`. But in the view you declared your model as a collection of objects `ListsVM`: `@model IEnumerable<Seating.ViewModels.ListsVM>`

Did you try to change the model declaration to `@model Seating.ViewModels.ListsVM`?

If to declare the view model as `@model Seating.ViewModels.ListsVM` then the `Model.Dths` will be referencing to correct collection and the `@foreach (var item in Model.Dths)` will enumerate this collection properly.

Comment: It was really that easy? I just had to remove IEnumerable from @model. The hours I've spent to learn I had to just delete one word... Thank you for fixing it.